# how to prevent the rename excel sheet in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am getting the reference error while saving the sheet because the existing Sheet name was RENAMED. So please guide to avoid the user to change the Sheet actual name or even though the user RENAME it, it will be renamed back to ORIGINAL name when the time of SAVEING data/Reload the page/Save changes.

Kindly help on this.

Thanks,
Sesha

Comment: Take a look at this: http://excel.tips.net/T002689_Locking_Worksheet_Names.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have several options here. You can store the sheet names of the worksheets in a xlVeryHidden sheet, and simply rename the sheets on a Workbook after save event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff836466.aspx

You can also simply reference the code names of the worksheets, which the user will not be able to change if you lock the VBA project.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837552.aspx

But all of this would require more detail from you regarding what you need.